# Django throws datetime.datetime has no attribute encode error when activating admin site

Tags: django, datetime, attributes, django-admin

When setting up the Django admin site, I get the following error. I am having a hard time debugging it because I can't tell where in my 'Announcement' model the problem is occurring. I've checked base.py on the line  where the problem occurs, but I don't really understand all of what is going on in that class.

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/main/announcment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1185, in render
    _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 286, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 264, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 256, in __init__
    super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 184, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 258, in lookup_field
    value = attr()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 433, in __str__
    return force_text(self).encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Show us code of your `Announcement` model.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your Annoucement model, it's hard to tell, but it seems probable that you are returning a `datetime` from your `__unicode__` method, instead of an actual unicode string.